# $\lfloor \frac{4x-3}{16} \rfloor+\lfloor \frac{4x-1}{16} \rfloor+\lfloor \frac{4x+1}{16} \rfloor+\lfloor \frac{4x+3}{16} \rfloor =23$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the $x$ :

$$\left\lfloor \frac{4x-3}{16} \right\rfloor+\left\lfloor \frac{4x-1}{16} \right\rfloor+\left\lfloor \frac{4x+1}{16} \right\rfloor+\left\lfloor \frac{4x+3}{16} \right\rfloor =23$$

---

$$\lfloor \frac{x}{4}+\frac{-3}{16} \rfloor+\lfloor \frac{x}{4}+\frac{-1}{16} \rfloor+\lfloor \frac{x}{4}+\frac{+1}{16} \rfloor+\lfloor \frac{x}{4}+\frac{+3}{16} \rfloor =23$$

But I do not know what to do please help me !

Comment: What about $x$? Is it real, rational?

Answer (score 1):

Let us denote as $\{x\}$ the fractional part of $x$, i.e. $x-\lfloor x\rfloor$. The given equation is equivalent to

$$x-\left[\left\{\frac{4x-3}{16}\right\}+\left\{\frac{4x-1}{16}\right\}+\left\{\frac{4x+1}{16}\right\}+\left\{\frac{4x+3}{16}\right\}\right] = 23$$
where the term between square brackets is a real number in the interval $[0,4]$ and a $4$-periodic function, whose derivative, where existing, equals $1$. By substituting $x=23+z$ the given problem turns out to be equivalent to solving
$$z=\left\{\frac{4z+9}{16}\right\}+\left\{\frac{4z+11}{16}\right\}+\left\{\frac{4z+13}{16}\right\}+\left\{\frac{4z+15}{16}\right\}$$
over the interval $z\in[0,4]$. The last identity holds for any $z\in\left[\frac{5}{4},\frac{7}{4}\right)$: the difference between the RHS and the LHS is a piecewise-constant function over sub-intervals of $[0,4]$ having a length that is a multiple of $\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: why :
$$z=\left\{\frac{4z+9}{16}\right\}+\left\{\frac{4z+11}{16}\right\}+\left\{\frac{4z+13}{16}\right\}+\left\{\frac{4z+15}{16}\right\}$$

Comment: It is a consequence of the fact that the fractional part of a equals the fractional part of a+1.

Answer (score 1):

Say $a= \lfloor \frac{4x-3}{16} \rfloor $, $b= \lfloor \frac{4x-1}{16} \rfloor $,     $c= \lfloor \frac{4x+1}{16} \rfloor $ and $d= \lfloor \frac{4x+3}{16} \rfloor $.

Since $\frac{4x-3}{16} - \frac{4x-3}{16}  = \frac{3}{8} < 1$ we have $0\leq d-a \leq 1$.

So $a\leq b\leq c\leq d\in \{n,n+1\}$ for some $n\in \mathbb{Z}$

Case 1. $a=b=c=d=n$ then $4n=23$, impossible.

Case 2. $a=b=c= n$ and $d={n+1}$ then $4n+1=23$, impossible.

Case 3. $a=b=n$ and $c=d={n+1}$ then $4n+2=23$, impossible.

Case 4. $a= n$ and $b=c=d={n+1}$ then $4n+3=23$, so $n=5$.

Since $a=5$ we have $$5\leq\frac{4x-3}{16}<6$$ and since $b=6$ we have $$6\leq \frac{4x-1}{16}<7$$ so $x\in [{97\over 4},{99\over 4})$.

Comment: why $a\leq b\leq c\leq d\in \{n,n+1\}$ for some $n\in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Because $0\leq d-a \leq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let ${4x-3\over16}=u$. Then the equation becomes

$$\left\lfloor u\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor u+{1\over8}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor u+{2\over8}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor u+{3\over8}\right\rfloor=23$$

Since each term on the right hand side is an integer and

$$\left\lfloor u\right\rfloor\le\left\lfloor u+{1\over8}\right\rfloor\le\left\lfloor u+{2\over8}\right\rfloor\le\left\lfloor u+{3\over8}\right\rfloor\le\left\lfloor u\right\rfloor+1$$

we must have $\lfloor u\rfloor=5$ and $\left\lfloor u+{1\over8}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor u+{2\over8}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor u+{3\over8}\right\rfloor=6$. This is satisfied when $5\le u\lt6$ and $6\le u+{1\over8}$. (Note, $u\lt6$ automatically implies $u+{3\over8}\lt7$.) Together this means $5{7\over8}\le u\lt6$, or

$${47\over8}\le{4x-3\over16}\lt6$$

which simplifies to

$${97\over4}\le x\lt{99\over4}$$

Answer (score 0):

As a first observation, it looks to me easy to show that the function is even for $x$ an integer.

Since the numerators differ by $6$ and you are dividing by $16$ there can be at most one change of value in the floor function as you go from lowest to highest. Taking the lowest term as $n$ you have either $4n=23, 4n+1=23, 4n+2=23, 4n+4=23$ to tell you where you want the change to happen.

Since the function is even at integers this gives you an interval of length $1$ to explore, and a little analysis should enable you to do better than that. Do actually calculate the function for a few values of $x$ to see what is going on and to see how close you can get to the answer you want.